# Heroku error with windows

Tags: heroku-toolbelt

When I tried login with heroku login and password with windows command prompt i got this error:

```
connection attempt failed errorno:ETIMEDOUT SOCKET ERROR
```

Can someone please let me know how to go through the process

Answer (score 0):

There are a few github issues from people facing [a similar issue](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/407) in the past. They determined that problem is probably related to the user's network configuration blocking traffic on port 5000.